# adding marker listener in a loop in google maps api v3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a bunch of markers and wish to add a mouseover handler to each of them. I am looping through my coordinates, creating new markers and then adding a handler. In the handler I wish for it to modify the DOM element with a specific id.

The problem is, even though in the loop the id is changing through each iteration, the actual handler applied all use the last postId generated.

```
for(i in results)
{
    r=results[i][0];
    var postId=results[i][1]; // Different for each i
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
    {
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: r[0].geometry.location
        }));
        console.log(postId); 
        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[markers.length-1], 'mouseover', function() {
            console.log(postId);
        });
    } 
}
```

The problem is that no matter which marker I hover over, postId is being printed out as "1".

However when I am going through the loop, the postId is different each time.

**Console output:**

```
21
20
12
10
9
3
2
1
```

However, when I hover over the markers it always says 1.

Comment: Does alert(postID) in the event have the same issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you create one global `postId` that all listeners share. You can create private versions like so:

```
(function () {
    var postId=results[i][1];
    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[markers.length-1], 'mouseover', function() {
        console.log(postId);
    });
})();
```

Comment: Great answer .. Very helpful to explain that a private version is needed.